# Ruby - if all from relation attributes are equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relation

this one I guess is going to be simple.

I have Rooms and I have Clients. Each room can have many clients.

In my room #1 I have 4 clients, and they are all female (client.sex = "F").

I want to check if this is true or false. And I do this:

```
Room.first.clients.all? {|c| c.sex == "F" }
```

And that returns true! Which is cool. But lets think that sex could be "F", "M", "A", "B", "C" "N" and I want to check if all the clients of one specific room have the same sex. How could I do that?

```
Room.first.clients.all? {|c| c.sex == "same as all other clients from this room" }
```

Of course I could do:

```
sexbase = Room.first.clients.first.sex
Room.first.clients.all? {|c| c.sex == sexbase }
```

But it there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has less database retrievals...

```
array = Room.first.clients.pluck(:sex)
array.count(array[0]) == array.count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even check it with single database query:

```
Room.first.clients.distinct.count(:sex) > 1
```

Here you count distinct sex values in your relation, and if it's more than 1 than you have some different values there.

Also, if you are interested in values presented, you may extract array of distinct values and then check it' size:

```
values = Room.first.clients.distinct.pluck(:sex) # ['M', 'F'] or ['M'], for example
values.size > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to use "distinct", very interesting.

Comment: But it is returning 0 even though I have two different "sexes" in a room. I get this in my console when using pluck:
NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Arel::Nodes::Distinct:0x0000000a1a45a0>